# Execute command after broken SSH connection

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, shell, openssh

Is there a way to execute a command after an SSH connection is broken (blackout etc.)? When I normally log off I can just use .bash_logout but I don't know what to do when my connection breaks.

Comment: Since i havent tested this I will leave this as a comment instead. Try executing the SSH command together with an or statement. :~$ ssh foo.bar || "command to remove tunnell". The only issue I can see with this is if SSH returns something else than 0 under normal operation.

Answer (score 0):

You could run commands based on a signal trap.  Usually a disconnection would end the shell with a SIGPIPE, so add this to the .bash_profile

```
trap "echo do your command here; exit" 13
```

You need the "exit" otherwise the shell won't close as a result of the trap.

Comment: I will give it a try. I just want it to remove my tunneled unix socket (I use it for few scripts).